# what is the difference between these two Integration over Region?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

```
integ1 = Integrate[x^2, Element[{x, y}, Region[Disk[{0, 0}, 1]]]]
(*  ==> Pi/4 *)
integ2 = Integrate[x^2, Element[x, Region[Disk[{0, 0}, 1]]]]
(*  ==> {Pi/4, Pi/4} *)
```

If the region integrated over is irregular, such as a `Polygon`, the `integ2` will give two different values.

I was wondered by the behavior of `integ2`. Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second example, `x ∈ Disk[{0, 0}, 1]` (I dropped the unnecessary [`Region`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region) wrapper) means that `x` is a 2-element list. In effect, the second integral is equivalent to:

```
Integrate[{x, y}^2, {x, y} ∈ Disk[{0, 0}, 1]]
```

> {π/4, π/4}

Comment: A brief lesson! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
Integrate[x^2, Element[{x, y}, Region[Disk[{0, 0}, {1, 2}]]]]
(*\[Pi]/2*)
Integrate[y^2, Element[{x, y}, Region[Disk[{0, 0}, {1, 2}]]]]
(*2 \[Pi]*)
Integrate[a^2, Element[a, Region[Disk[{0, 0}, {1, 2}]]]]
(*{\[Pi]/2,2 \[Pi]}*)
```

Change the integral area, and the difference maybe become obvious.